# Docker with Java: path RUN javac

Tags: java, docker

I have a problem with RUN javac in Dockerfile:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
RUN javac ../src/Hello.java
RUN java -cp ../src Hello
```

Hello.java

```
public class Hello 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

When I build Dockerfile, I have this error:

> javac: file not found: ../src/Hello.java

My project "HelloWorld" has this structure:

- docker-dir

  - docker-compose.yml
  - Dockerfile
- src

  - Hello

Comment: Try using the shell of the container before writing the Dockerfile

Comment: And what is `../src`? How did you add that to the container? Where is the entry point?

Comment: Dockerfile is into docker-dir folder, Hello is into the src folder

Comment: The src folder isn't automatically added to your container

Comment: And how added src folder in my container?

Comment: Ses the Dockerfile directive COPY or ADD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RUN` command only operates on the container's file system, not the host's. You have to copy the files from your local file system to the container's file system:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
COPY src /src
RUN javac /src/Hello.java
```

Many developers finds that they want to separate their build container from the run container. The container that's running software typically has much less requirements on its environment than the build container (e.g. no JDK installed, just the JRE).

For that your build container would be:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY src /src
RUN javac /src/Hello.java
RUN docker build -t foo . && docker push foo
```

and your run-container would be

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
RUN java /src/Hello
```

Remember to mount in `/var/lib/docker.sock` for `docker build` to work

Comment: with the first solution, COPY src /src, I have "Service 'web' failed to build: lstat src: no such file or directory", I think because I'm in docker-dir folder; if I change "COPY src /src" into "COPY ../src /src" I have "Service 'web' failed to build: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../src"

Comment: @freedev - Guys, is it possible to mount directory from host file system into Docker container file system?

Comment: 1. Have your `Dockerfile` at the root of your project, you may only reference directories at the same level or deeper than the docker file
2. @Vadim Yes, `docker run -v /Users/me/foo:/foo ubuntu:latest` will mount `/Users/me/foo` on the hosts file system to `/foo` in the container

Comment: and how can do to add file Hello in the container? Dockerfile is inside docker-dir

Comment: You can't have the `Dockerfile` in a separate directory to your code, it needs to be in the same directory as your code or above.

Comment: Thanks, I have move the src folder inside the docker-dir folder, javac running but not java: in the container log I have: Error: Could not find or load main class Hello

Answer (score 0):

You have first to copy the file inside your docker instance and then you can compile it.

To copy the file `COPY` or `ADD`, for example:

```
RUN mkdir /src
ADD Hello.java /src/
RUN cd / && javac /src/Hello.java
RUN java -cp /src Hello
```

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory '/src': Permission denied

Comment: Because of docker instance you've chosen. Try alpine java.  jboss/wildfly is for web apps

Comment: I have the same error: Service 'web' failed to build: lstat Hello.java: no such file or directory

Comment: @ChiaraPerino I repeat: you have to change your docker `FROM` using a different base for example `openjdk:8` or alpine java, have a look at docker hub.

Comment: I have changed FROM with alpine but I have the same initial problem

Comment: @ChiaraPerino Strange. Try adding `USER root` after FROM

Comment: the problem is that I have src folder in the same level of docker-dir: if I move src folder inside docker-dir folder, it's works (with openjdk:8, not with alpine). isn't there a method to create a structure with docker-dir and src folder in the same level?

Comment: @ChiaraPerino two things: first is not clear what do you mean with docker-dir. the folder where your Dockerfile is? The current working directory in your docker instance? Second, you can't expect we write a tutorial using the comments. Please follow my suggestion: assign your preference with up votes and, if possible, mark an answer as correct. Then write a new question trying to clearly reproduce the new problem you're experiencing.